# mongodb trigger aggregator expression not working

Tags: mongodb

```
const countercollection = context.services.get(serviceName).db(changeEvent.ns.db).collection("CounterCollection");
const eventlogcollection = context.services.get(serviceName).db(changeEvent.ns.db).collection(changeEvent.ns.coll);
var which_counter_to_query = Math.floor((Math.random()*10));
var counter = await countercollection.findOneAndUpdate(
 { _id:  "counter" + which_counter_to_query},
 { 
 $set: { 
  "count": { 
      $cond: { 
         
          if: { $gt: [ { $add: [ "$count", 1 ] }, "$max" ] }, 
          then: "$min", 
          else: { $add: [ "$count", 1] } 

      } 
     } 
    }
 }
  ,
  { writeConcern: 'majority',returnNewDocument: true, upsert : true}
 );

var updateRes = await eventlogcollection.updateOne({_id : docId},{ $set : {sequenceId : counter.count}});
```

i was expecting next value of count from counter collection . which has values like

```
{"_id":"counter0","max":{"$numberLong":"999999999"},"count":{"$numberLong":"0"},"min":{"$numberLong":"0"}}
```

but in both collections after this trigger execution i am getting object in squenceId and count field like this

```
"sequenceId":{"$cond":{"if":{"$gt":[{"$add":["$count",{"$numberLong":"1"}]},"$max"]},"then":"$min","else":{"$add":["$count",{"$numberLong":"1"}]}}}
```

i was expecting sequence id like sequenceId:1 or 2 or 3 etc

can anyone help

I referred following links

[counter increment till max in mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-restrict-a-fields-value-while-updating-using-inc/16414/3)

[mongodb autoincrement](https://www.mongodb.com/basics/mongodb-auto-increment)

[generating globally unique identifier in mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb)

> Blockquote